# .dtx calling command from class

Tags: document-classes

I am writing a .dtx file and want to call a command from my class; however, the .dtx file requires ltxdoc as its class. How can I demonstrate the output of a command from my class within the .dtx file? pdfpages doesn't seem to do the trick, as it includes a whole page from another document.

---

Edit 1: Here is a minimal example of my preamble for my .dtx file, which is based on: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/dtxtut/dtxtut.pdf

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
% Copywrite (C) 2018 by Me
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later
% version. The latest version of this license is in:
%
% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of
% LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% \fi
%

% \iffalse 
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{EXAMPLE.dtx}
%</driver>
%<class>\NeedTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
%<class>\ProvidesClass{EXAMPLE}
%<*class> [2018-12-01 v01.01]
%

%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
\DocInput{EXAMPLE.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use `ltxdoc`  which is just a thin wrapper around `article` class, inputting `doc.sty` you can use your own class, and add `\usepackage{doc}` in the preamble.

Here is the output of your MWE modified to use `article.cls` but you could just as easily use the class that is being documented.

[image]

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
% Copywrite (C) 2018 by Me
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3 of this license or (at your option) any later
% version. The latest version of this license is in:
%
% http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of
% LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% \fi
%

% \iffalse 
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{EXAMPLE.dtx}
%</driver>
%<class>\NeedTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2005/12/01]
%<class>\ProvidesClass{EXAMPLE}
%<*class> [2018-12-01 v01.01]
%\fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*driver>
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{doc,color,soul}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
\DocInput{EXAMPLE.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
```

Comment: @Justapigeon added an example

Comment: @Justapigeon all three of those commands are defined by `doc.sty` not `ltxdoc.cls` so will be defined if you load `doc` package, you do not need `ltxdoc` for those.

Comment: @Justapigeon if the class defines a command and you are using that class, how can the command be undefined?

Comment: @Justapigeon that was the point of my answer, you should use EXAMPLE.cls not article, I only used article as you had not provided EXAMPLE.cls that I could use.

Comment: @Justapigeon not in general but you have given no clue as to the contents of the file. If you want the commands to be available in multiple classes write them as a package not a class, your class can then have \RequirePaackage{...} to include them automatically and when using article you can use \usepackage{thepackagewiththecommands}

Comment: it doesn't seem at all redundant to me. You still have given no example but either the commands are closely tied to one class, in which case you should use that class to document itself or if using a different class for the documentation, the commands are not available so you can describe them but not actually use them in the documentation.  Or the commands are not closely tied to the class and could be used in other classes including the class you use for documentation, in which case they should be in a package. That's how it is intended to work.

Comment: @Justapigeon as I say you have given no example, but it seems that you are making it sound more complicated than it is. It is a perfectly simple choice. You can define the commands to be available in just one class (if they are in a class file) or define them to be available in multiple classes (if they are in a package).  Of course tex being tex there are always alternatives as you could always locally redefine enough of the class loading commands that you can `\input` your class file it into the documentation, but any details there are fragile and highly dependent on code you have not shown.